# FirebaseAuth.Instance is null when Firebase Analytics libraries are installed Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

I have got a Xamarin Forms Solution that works perfectly with the Firebase Auth Xamarin Firebase.Auth **version 71.1605.0**.

**Android**

Installing these two libraries:

- Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics **version 71.1630.0**
- Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl **version 71.1630.0**

The firebase auth stopped working and `FirebaseAuth.Instance` is always null.

**iOS**

The app does not even load for me to see what the exception is.

Is there a way to resolve this or it is not possible to have both Firebase Auth and Analytics in the same Xamarin Forms Solution?

Comment: Did you add the JSON files in respective projects?

Comment: Yes I did or is there a different JSON file specifically for integrating firebase analytics?

Comment: https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/26/firebase-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/ 
This might help you!!

Comment: @Jaymin I think you need to read my question properly. The issue is that I can't have auth and analytics in the same solution.

Comment: I have a feeling there was something wrong while installing the NuGet packages which could be one of the reasons you are facing the above-mentioned issues, I would suggest you remove the added packages and add `Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl` from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics.Impl/ Also make sure that once you remove it the instance is still null or not

Comment: I did that and it didn't resolve the issue @FreakyAli

Comment: so even after removing the Analytics packages still your `FirebaseAuth` is not working?

Comment: It does work when I exclude the analytics packages. After further investigation, adding both analytics and auth packages, trying to get the auth instance result in this error `Firebase.FirebaseException: firebase-auth is not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode.`

Comment: It seems to be a known issue with Xamarin's Firebase libraries, apparently it's not specific to Auth+Analytics, but using any two services in the same project causes it. The only workaround I could find is to downgrade all packages to v60. It remains unfixed for four months now, I'm starting to give up hope. See: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/223